# Why H-bridge isn't working properly?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, h-bridge

I am making a circuit to control a motor using an Arduino UNO and an H-bridge IC, but it's not working, rather something strange is happening.

Circuit's scheme:
[image: scheme for my circuit]

When the motor is connected to pins 3 and 6 of the H-bridge nothing happens, but strangely when one of the motor's wires is connected to either 3 or 6 pins of the H-bridge, and the other wire of the motor is connected to ground the motor works! But I can't control it's speed with the potentiometer, neither control it's direction, or even it off using the push-buttons.

I suppose that the H-bridge deliver power to it's 3 and 6 pins because the motor works when connected to ground and one of them, but this shouldn't happen, one of the pins (3 and 6) should deliver power and the other should be ground, that's what I think.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit:
For some reason the wires connecting Arduino pin 2 with H-bridge pin 7 won't deliver 5 power unless I was touching the wire with my finger, (this also happen in the wire between Arduino pin 3 and H-bridge pin 2) I've tried connecting the pins with other wires, but the same thing happens, also I've used an 220Ω resistor and the problem is still happening. this thing happens with all Arduino pins, not just 2 and 3, but in before this project they were working very well. O_o

Comment: The L293D is an ancient, horribly lossy part and performance on a mere 5v supply will be absolutely terrible.  You may well have an additional problem, but even when "working" the results will not be pleasing.  You should 1) use a motor supply that is *not* the Arduino's 5v rail, 2) use an FET bridge  not a darlington one like the L293/L298 and 3) verify that all connections are correct both theoretically and as actually built

Comment: ... and then verify that the chip inputs and outputs are working. If you still have problems you will have to look at (1) the wiring between the microcontroller and the driver and (2) your code.

Comment: I made sure everything was working (except H-bridge internal connections), so the problem is absolutely from the H-bridge itself?

Comment: Or from the assumption that you can reasonably use this H-bridge chip at 5V.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen what do you mean? Is 5V low or high for H-bridge?

Comment: And L293 can have a combined drop voltage of ~ 2.5V, which (at 5V) leaves 2.5V for your motor. Can it run on that voltage?

Comment: Even more important, look at the actual voltages on the 293 pins. If pin 7 is always high, and pin 2 is always high, this would explain what you are seeing. The upper element is turned on and the lower element is not. So a motor will get no current unless one side of the motor is connected to ground. Likewise, what are the output voltages when the motor is connected?  Always check your circuit details before you start blaming your software.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I checked that, I made sure that 2 and 7 aren't both high at the same time.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen As I know, the H-bridge gets it's power from its pin 16, and the motor get power from H-bridge's pin 8.

Comment: OK, you are using 9V for the motor power? That's better. But can that battery actually provide the current?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Yeah, the motor works very well when connected directly to the battery, so the problem is not in the battery neither in the motor.

Comment: For some reason the wires connecting Arduino pin 2 with H-bridge pin 7 won't deliver power unless I was touching the wire with my finger, (this also happen in the wire between Arduino pin 3 and H-bridge pin 2) I've tried connecting the pins with other wires, but the same thing happens, also I've used an 220Ω resistor and the problem is still happening. this thing happens with all Arduino pins, not just 2 and 3, but in before this project they were working very well.

Comment: I think this has something to do with human skin's resistance

Comment: I tried connecting the pins using a wire, a 220Ω resistor, a 10KΩ resistor, a 1MΩ resistor, and always I get the same result: the motor won't work unless I was touching the wire, and also the motor works very weakly, sometimes it runs slowly but sometimes it can't even rotate, only produce some noise.